# Why all the spans are changed instead of one?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have prev and next button:

This is function of next button:

```
var nextFn = function(e)
    {
        var current = $('.active');
        alert(current);
        var prev = $('#prev');
        pos = $('.active').attr('id');

        $("#num").text('(' + pos + '/' + researchPlaces.length + ')');


        $(current).next().attr("class", "active");
        $(current).attr("class", "passive"); 
        //e.stopPropagation();          
    };
```

When I click next, it supposed to show the next span. However, it also shows the next span in other li(s) in the page.

```
 <li class="memberElement" style="width: 100%; padding: 10px 0 10px 0; border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;">
    <div class="MemberImageHolder" style="float:left">
        <a href="#">
            <img class="memberpic" src="picture.php?action=display&amp;contentType=members&amp;id=5&amp;quality=medium" alt="">
        </a>
    </div>
    <div class="memberDetails">
        <a href="#!uottawa/members/5/profile">Charles Darwin</a>
        <div id="title">Professor</div><div id="unit">
            <b>University of Ottawa</b>
        </div>
        <div id="address">
            <a id="prev">Prev </a>
            <span id="1" class="active">150 York Street</span>
            <span id="2" class="passive">80 Elgin Street</span>
            <span id="num" class="passive">(0/2)</span>
            <a id="next"> Next</a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <span class="divider"></span>
</li>
```

This is my one of the li(s). What's wrong?

Comment: We need more information/code. How is this function being called?

Comment: Please format your HTML code....

Comment: Do all your li's have a prev and next that are assigned the id of "prev" and "next"? Cause ID is supposed to be unique. You should start by looking there.

Comment: anchor element has a click event it called like that

Comment: I think you need to remove `active` class from each element.  You are adding it to the next element and adding `passive` class to the current but not removing the `active` class from the current.

Comment: if you could add a fiddle, it would be helpfull..

Comment: @GaryStorey I don't think so. OP uses `attr()` that changes it completely to the new value.

Comment: You have mutliple elements with active. The code does not magically know you only want the one in the list you are working with, you need to tell it that.

Comment: @MartinErnst You're right. Good catch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think is because of your selector :

```
$('.active');
```

This selector select all the control that has active class. I guess you have one active span in each li.

To modify class, you should use addClass instead of modifying the attribute :

```
$(current).next().addClass("active");
$(current).removeClass("passive");
```

This way you won't lose other class associated with your control.

**Edit :**

You can get the li by the link clicked :

```
$("#prev").click(function()
{
    var li = $(this).closest("li");
    var current = $(li).find('.active');
    alert(current);
    var prev = $('#prev');
    pos = $('.active').attr('id');

    $("#num").text('(' + pos + '/' + researchPlaces.length + ')');


    $(current).next().attr("class", "active");
    $(current).attr("class", "passive"); 
    //e.stopPropagation();          
});
```

Comment: Yes i have one active class in each li

Comment: still does not work. I think I should only take the clicked element as a current

Comment: You have to include the li in your selector. Like : $("#liID .active"). You must put something specific to your li

Comment: You can get the li by the link clicked. I edited my answer to show how.

Answer (score 0):

If each div with class 'address' is structured as in your code you can try:

```
var current = $(this).parent().find('.active');
```